# .NET garbage profiling: calculate how much garbage a piece of code is making

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I would like to write a utility class that will help me determine how much garbage a certain piece of code is making.

Something I can use like this:
`GarbageProfiler.Start();` and `int numGarbage = GarbageProfiler.End();`

Idea is simple enough. But does it make sense to do so? Are there any tools out there to do just this?

Comment: What do you mean when you say, "garbage"?

Comment: Define garbage. From a GC point of view everything is garbage, only some of it is collected later.

Comment: @Willem: Garbage is made up of objects that aren't reachable from GC roots. Presumably he wants to know how many bytes are allocated that are unreachable upon completion of his run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But does it make sense to do so?

No.

You would at least have to differentiate between the Generations of the garbage.

The memory that a certain piece of code allocates and *still holds* at the end is (can be) much more expensive than the objects it quickly released.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few memory profilers already out there. A quick search on Google will give you several.

There is even [an API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188781.aspx) for memory profiling .Net applications.

Comment: I tried it briefly, with the example provided, but it seems not to work.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of garbage that is behind a reference will change from run to run depending on whether the reference holds that last reference(s) to the objects or not. So predicting the amount of garbage is very hard.

There are also quite some performance counters that you can read just before a `GC.Collect()` and after it that could give you an idea.

I do question the use of this all; you will never know when the GC kicks in so you do not know when the garbage will be recycled. And calling GC.Collect() is not a very good idea (most of the time)

Comment: GC.Collect() could be a good idea in a Profiler. But I agree the whole thing is still pointless.